# Has the way that Blender handles PSD alphas changed?

Tags: image, transparency, shader-nodes

I've noticed this issue popping up in a few projects I've been working on, it seems like the way that Blender handles the alpha channel on PSD files within shader nodes has changed, resulting in this bright ghosting effect around the edge. Anyone else experiencing this?

It's not impossible that Adobe has changed the way they export alphas too

[image: Weird Ghostsing]

Comment: I should note that if I save this as a PNG the ghost disappears

Comment: Let me know you saw my answer, then I will vote to close your question. Bug topics are not allowed to discus here. Anyway thanks for pointing the issue.

Comment: Yeah I saw the answer, where does one discuss bug topics if not here?

Answer (score 0):

Since I felt deep into this ...

### Short

Blender 3.2 works ... it is a [bug (confirmed)](https://developer.blender.org/T102942) since Blender 3.3 ...

[image]

### Long

There seems to be a "basic" support for PSD, so it has its glitches :) It seems to me like Blender see PSD as single layered file. So if your store transparency in a solo Alpha channel it is not seen by Blender ([discussed here](https://developer.blender.org/T99221)).

[image]

For transparency stored in RGB channels (what assume is called Premultiplied) it should work (for bug fixed version).

[image]

Same behaviour for Alpha channel used as Mask Layer in Photoshop.

[image]

What worked for me as workaround (with this bug) was to set Alpha > **Channel Packed**, that is weird (it is designed for a different purpose, but it worked here).

[image]

Also when PSD is Packed into Blender it works too :)

Comment: I'll give that a try next time it makes an appearance, I suppose it's not the end of the world to just save the docs as PNGs, but sometimes working on live docs as PSDs can be useful!